# C# Windows Form - How reference created in runtime new textbox/side label (also created in runtime)?

Tags: c#, reference, textbox, runtime, label

its possible for example:

form start with 1 textbox(name: textbox1) and 1 label(name: label1)
in runtime is created textbox and label (side-side) so in runtime we can have

```
label1 - textbox1
label2 - textbox2
label3 - textbox3
label4 - textbox4
```

How reference these futures textbox/labels in code before compile executable without have error that these textbox/labels dont exist (yet) ?

only for everybody know, i create new textbox and labels in runtime this way:

```
            n++;
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            txt.Name = "textbox" + n;
            txt.Text = "";
            txt.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(189, 26);
            txt.Location = new Point(87, n2);
            testelogico = txt.Name;
            gpbCategoria.Controls.Add(txt);
            txt.TextChanged += new EventHandler(new_onchange);
            txt.Leave += new EventHandler(erase_onLeave);

            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Name = "label" + n;
            lbl.Text = "Acessório Nº" + n + ":";
            lbl.Location = new Point(4, n2 + 5);
            gpbCategoria.Controls.Add(lbl);
```

In another part of code i would like to refer for example:

```
If (textbox4.Text == "" && label4.Name == "Acessório Nº4:")
{
gpbCategoria.Controls.Remove(textbox4);
gpbCategoria.Controls.Remove(label4);
}
```

but i will have error because these labels not exist yet (only will be created i runtime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are generating the controls dynamically, so the compiler has no idea what `textBox4` is BEFORE it is even created. What you can do though is to search for that control by its name during runtime:

```
TextBox textbox4 = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("textbox4", false).FirstOrDefault();

if (textbox4 == null)
{
    throw new Exception("Could not find textbox4.");
}
```

This will search for `textbox4` in `Form.Controls` and will throw an exception if it doesn't exist. You can follow the same pattern for `labels` or any other control in the form.

Comment: It worked great, incuding use options like textbox4.Name, .Text all works like it was correct textbox, thank you very much for this, only thing i changed was change this.Controls to gpbCategoria.Controls

Comment: No problem. Please mark it as the answer if you think it was what you were looking for.

Comment: Only one problem here: if i refer textbox4 it will run without error but if i execute code and this texbox4 not exist yet i have crash and report follow error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object (because not exist this textbox4 yet), understood ? Know how solve it ? Thanks.

Comment: i will mark, sure !! Only need to know how solve this last error that is giving if textbox was not created yet in runtime and i try execute code. Thanks for help

Comment: If the textbox is not created by the time you try to access it, `(TextBox)this.Controls.Find("textbox4", false).FirstOrDefault();` will return null and that is why we have that `if` block below it. You can change the `throw` statement to whatever logic you think suits your design best. Does that make sense?

Comment: i would like to make access these variables public, so i tried add: public partial class cad_produto_acessorios_novo : Form TextBox txtAcessorio4 = (TextBox)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("txtAcessorio", false).FirstOrDefault();, but i get error: Error 1 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'InfoEarth_Cad_Cliente.cad_produto_acessorios_novo.gpbCategoria

Comment: Will accept this answer and make new question to make it public. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the textbox by name:

```
var textbox = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Single(ctr => ctr.Name == "textboxname");
```

Comment: It also worked great change this for gpbCategoria, but i get same error that friend programmer93 code, for example if i refer textboxname4 it will run without error but if i execute code and this texboxname4 not exist yet i have crash and report follow error: Sequence contains no matching element (because not exist this textbox yet), understood ? Know how solve it ? Thanks

Comment: for you the TextBox name is "textbox4" not "textboxname4"

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net framework 4.0 or higher then you can use dynamic keyword:
Here goes the complete code for your reference:

```
public class Class1
{
    // Declare all the controls as dynamic
    dynamic textbox1, textbox2, textbox3, textbox4;
    dynamic label1, label2, label3, label4;

    public Class1()
    {
        // Create the actual object type, which they will hold at Run time. 
        textbox1 = textbox2 = textbox3 = textbox4 = new TextBox();
        label1 = label2 = label3 = label4 = new Label();

        // Loop through to create controls at Runtime.
        n++;
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.Name = "textbox" + n;
        txt.Text = "";
        txt.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(189, 26);
        txt.Location = new Point(87, n2);
        testelogico = txt.Name;
        gpbCategoria.Controls.Add(txt);
        txt.TextChanged += new EventHandler(new_onchange);
        txt.Leave += new EventHandler(erase_onLeave);

        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Name = "label" + n;
        lbl.Text = "Acessório Nº" + n + ":";
        lbl.Location = new Point(4, n2 + 5);
        gpbCategoria.Controls.Add(lbl);

    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        //Throw exception if controls are not initialized yet.
        if (textbox4 == null || label4 == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Controls not initialized.");
        }

        else
        {
            // You can access the control propoties similar to normal controls.
            if (textbox4.Text == "" && label4.Name == "Acessório Nº4:")
            {
                gpbCategoria.Controls.Remove(textbox4);
                gpbCategoria.Controls.Remove(label4);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How it works, dynamic txt = new TextBox(); ? How i will refere this in another place of my code ? Thanks

Comment: @felipeSalomao: Refer the updated code to achieve the same functionality using dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

It is much better to put Label - TextBox pare into UserControl.

Let UserControl have the index number passing through constructor

```
   public class MyUserControl : UserControl 
   {
      private readonly int index;

      public MyUserControl(int index)
      {
         this.index = index;

         InitializeComponent(); // will init you sub controls: label and textbox

         // set name to label

      } 

      public int Index
      {
         get { return index; }
      } 
   }
```

Use already suggested methods to find your user control by index in Controls collection and remove it if found.

Comment: Really not understood that, too much complex for me.. Rsrs Can you explain better ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi @programmer93 and @Jonesy, thanks for help, now it working fine see my final code (can help persons with same doubt that i had)

```
    TextBox txtAcessorio4 = (TextBox)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("txtAcessorio4", false).FirstOrDefault();
Label lblAcessorio4 = (Label)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("lblAcessorio4", false).FirstOrDefault();

                    if (txtAcessorio4 != null && txtAcessorio4.Text == "" && lblAcessorio4.Name == "lblAcessorio4")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Perfect");                           
                    }
```

Comment: Make sure you also check for `lblAcessorio4 != null` before you try to access `lblAcessorio4.Name`.

Comment: Ok, i will, i had doubt now, i would like to make access these variables public, so i tried add: public partial class cad_produto_acessorios_novo : Form
TextBox txtAcessorio4 = (TextBox)gpbCategoria.Controls.Find("txtAcessorio", false).FirstOrDefault();, but i get error: Error 1 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'InfoEarth_Cad_Cliente.cad_produto_acessorios_novo.gpbCategoria

Comment: the textboxes and labels belong to the class they're created in, so there's no easy way to access them from a different class. The best way to do this is to create a public property in the same class the controls are defined in and have that property return the control. Again, this is NOT a very good design, because you need to make sure the form is always running in order for the control to be accessible by other objects.